# Difference between @property and property()

Tags: python, properties, decorator, python-decorators

Is there a difference between

```
class Example(object):
    def __init__(self, prop):
        self._prop = prop

    def get_prop(self):
        return self._prop

    def set_prop(self, prop):
        self._prop = prop

    prop = property(get_prop, set_prop)
```

and

```
class Example2(object):
    def __init__(self, prop):
        self._prop = prop

    @property
    def prop(self):
        return self._prop

    @prop.setter
    def prop(self, prop):
        self._prop = prop
```

They seem to do the same thing, which doesn't fit python's goal of there being only one obvious way to do things. Is there a prefered way? And if so, why?

Comment: the decorator is just syntactic sugar - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/python-how-does-the-property-decorator-work

Comment: ok thanks, does anyone know why it was added?

Comment: you should take a look at this PEP. http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/

Comment: The `@someDecoratorFunction` was added to make the syntax prettier and easier to use. Like many things, it’s just syntactic sugar for other, more complex, language constructs.

Comment: @BoshWash: Python 2.4 added decorators, Python 2.6 added the `property.setter()` (and sibling) decorators. `property` has existed since 2.2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `@decorator` syntax is just syntactic sugar. There are no differences between the two approaches other than the syntax, the end result is the same.

```
@property
def prop(self):
    return self._prop
```

is translated to:

```
def prop(self):
    return self._prop
prop = property(prop)
```

and the same applies to the setter:

```
@prop.setter
def prop(self, prop):
    self._prop = prop
```

becomes:

```
tmp = prop.setter
def prop(self, prop):
    self._prop = prop
prop = tmp(prop)
```

as the decorator expression (`prop.setter`) is evaluated first.  See [How does the @property decorator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/python-how-does-the-property-decorator-work/17330273#17330273) for how `.setter()` (and `.deleter()` and `.getter()`) works.

Note that the `prop.setter()` decorator (and the `.getter()` and `.deleter()` decorators) of property objects was only added in Python 2.6. In addition, `property` was added to Python in version 2.2, but decorators were only added to the language in [Python 2.4](http://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.4.html#pep-318-decorators-for-functions-and-methods).

As a result, a lot of documentation still uses the older `property` constructor method.

If you are coding for Python 2.6 or newer, however, you should be using the decorators syntax.

The `@property` and `@prop.setter` decorators give a clear *early* visual signal that you have property functions here, while the separate `prop = property(...)` line after the property functions is easily missed, especially if the property implementation is longer.

Comment: @JayanthKoushik: Python has always had the ability to get certain things done in different ways with syntax. List comprehensions versus a loop, `try:`/`finally:` to open and close files vs. context managers and `with`. Newer syntax takes some time to become the preferred way, older documentation lingers, etc. That doesn't mean Python suddenly is inconsistent or that a principle is being violated.

Comment: Thanks, I guess it was to new to be removed in python 3.

Comment: @BoshWash: *new to be removed*? The `property()` constructor signature is not going to go away, not in Python 3 either. It's just that the `@prop.setter()` syntax is relatively new and code that needs to support Python 2.4 or 2.5 cannot use it.

Comment: Ok, so it will coexist as a different way of expressing the same thing, with a few more lines?

Comment: @BoshWash: They coexist but the `@property` syntax is cleaner.

Comment: I'll promise to let it go after that, but why is it cleaner?

Comment: @BoshWash: The separate `prop = property(..)` line comes after the functions, and can more easily be missed. The `@property` and `@prop.setter()` syntax *before* each property function is a clearer visual signal that you have property functions there.

Answer (score 0):

For your exact code I made a comparison in Python 3.7. 
[image]

This shows that stack machine Python bitecode will be a bit different, but almost identical.